# Why this schema is generating a relation n:m

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I've this schema.yml file (just relevant part):

```
SdrivingMaquina:
  actAs: 
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    idmaquina: { type: integer(8), autoincrement: true, notnull: true, primary: true }
    idempresa: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    patente: { type: string(12), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Empresa: { local: idempresa, class: SdrivingEmpresa, type: one, foreignType: one, foreignAlias: MaquinaEmpresa, onDelete: CASCADE, onUpdate: CASCADE }
SdrivingMaquinaEmisor:
  actAs: 
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    idmaquinaemisor: { type: integer(8), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    idmaquina: { type: integer(8), notnull: true }
    idemisor: { type: integer(8), notnull: true }
  relations:
    SdrivingEmisor: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: idemisor, foreign: idemisor, type: one }
    SdrivingMaquina: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: idmaquina, foreign: idmaquina, type: one }
```

Then after I run the task `symfony doctrine:build-model` I check the class `BaseSdrivingMaquina.class.php` and I can see this code:

```
public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasOne('SdrivingEmpresa as Empresa', array(
             'local' => 'idempresa',
             'foreign' => 'id',
             'onDelete' => 'CASCADE',
             'onUpdate' => 'CASCADE'));

        $this->hasOne('SdrivingEmpresa', array(
             'local' => 'idempresa',
             'foreign' => 'idempresa'));

        $this->hasMany('SdrivingMaquinaEmisor', array(
             'local' => 'idmaquina',
             'foreign' => 'idmaquina'));

        $timestampable0 = new Doctrine_Template_Timestampable();
        $this->actAs($timestampable0);
    }
```

When I try to insert any record I get this error:

> Couldn't call Doctrine_Core::set(), second argument should be an
>   instance of Doctrine_Collection when setting one-to-many references.

Which make me think that the error is the relation. This post is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288397/doctrine-record-exception-couldnt-call-doctrine-coreset-while-try-to-save/) can any tell me what's wrong or where is my mistake?

Comment: An example of the code that is generating the error would be useful.

Comment: @moote the code is in the related post, take a look at there (for not repeat the same here)

Comment: It's many-to-one because it's the default these kind of relations. Is it correct or you want one-to-one? (write `SdrivingMaquina: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: idmaquina, foreign: idmaquina, type: one, foreignType: one }` then) Sorry, but it's really hard to understand your example code as it's not in english and not uses conventions, but maybe it's just me... :)

Comment: @1ed yes I want one-to-one and what's the difference between this `SdrivingMaquina: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: idmaquina, foreign: idmaquina, type: one, foreignType: one }` and what I've? Or you mean remove the `SdrivingEmisor` relation?

Comment: `foreignType: one` at the end :) ... and by the way the two `$this->hasOne('SdrivingEmpresa ...)` relation looks very suspicious to me... maybe you should check that too.

Comment: @1ed don't know why `$this->hasOne('SdrivingEmpresa ...)` but after correct the error of `foreignType: one` things are working, the problem now is when I try to edit the saved values but this is another post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a one-to-one relation you should write

```
SdrivingMaquina: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: idmaquina, foreign: idmaquina, type: one, foreignType: one }
```

so add the `foreignType: one` parameter.