# Get and set the current value from the relationship between "maquina" and "emisor"

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Related to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299823/why-this-schema-is-generating-a-relation-nm/) and [this other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288397/doctrine-record-exception-couldnt-call-doctrine-coreset-while-try-to-save/) I'm experimenting a issue. This is the `SdrivingMaquinForm.class.php` code:

```
class SdrivingMaquinaForm extends BaseSdrivingMaquinaForm {

    protected $current_user;

    public function configure() {
        $this->current_user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser();

        unset($this['updated_at'], $this['created_at']);

        $this->widgetSchema['idempresa'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
        $id_empresa = $this->current_user->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
        $this->setDefault('idempresa', $id_empresa);

        $this->widgetSchema['no_emisor'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'SdrivingEmisor', 'add_empty' => 'Seleccione un Emisor', 'table_method' => 'fillChoice'));
        $this->validatorSchema['idempresa'] = new sfValidatorPass();
        $this->validatorSchema['no_emisor'] = new sfValidatorPass();
    }

    protected function doUpdateObject($values) {
        parent::doUpdateObject($values);

        if (isset($this['no_emisor'])) {
            if ($this->isNew()) {
                $sdrivingMaquinaEmisor = new SdrivingMaquinaEmisor();
                $this->getObject()->setSdrivingMaquinaEmisor($sdrivingMaquinaEmisor);
            } else {
                $sdrivingMaquinaEmisor = $this->getObject()->getSdrivingMaquinaEmisor();
            }

            $sdrivingMaquinaEmisor->setIdemisor($this->values['no_emisor']);
        }
    }

}
```

And it works perfectly, if I create a new `maquina` values are saved correctly, if I edit a existent record once again values are saved correctly and if I delete a record then the relation is deleted too. So the problem is not in actions or method. The problem I'm having is when user select to **edit** the existent record. Field `idempresa` and `patente` (see the schema.yml at first post metioned here) gets theirs values but `no_emisor` doesn't so every time I want to edit the record I got the select with values, yes, but the selected value isn't the right because I get the `add_empty` value. How I fix that? Meaning how I assign the default value for the select based on the one existent on the relation between `maquina` and `emisor`?

**EDIT: working on a possible solution**

I'm trying this code:

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request) {
        $this->forward404Unless($sdriving_maquina = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingMaquina')->find(array($request->getParameter('idmaquina'))), sprintf('Object sdriving_maquina does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('idmaquina')));
        $this->forward404Unless($sdriving_maquina_emisor = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingMaquinaEmisor')->find(array($request->getParameter('idmaquina'))), sprintf('Object sdriving_maquina_emisor does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('idmaquina')));

        $this->form = new SdrivingMaquinaForm($sdriving_maquina, $sdriving_maquina_emisor);
    }
```

But then how in the form `configure()` method I can access to `$sdriving_maquina_emisor` in order to use form `setDefault()` method?

**EDIT: `doUpdateObject($values)`**

See this is how my `doUpdateObject($values)` function looks like:

```
protected function doUpdateObject($values) {
    parent::doUpdateObject($values);

    if (isset($this['no_emisor'])) {
        if ($this->isNew()) {
            $sdrivingMaquinaEmisor = new SdrivingMaquinaEmisor();
            $this->getObject()->setSdrivingMaquinaEmisor($sdrivingMaquinaEmisor);
        } else {
            $sdrivingMaquinaEmisor = $this->getObject()->getSdrivingMaquinaEmisor();
        }

        $sdrivingMaquinaEmisor->setIdemisor($this->values['no_emisor']);
    }
}
```

Where exactly feet the code you leave for `doUpdateObject()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these situations you always have to do 2 things:

- load the default value from the doctrine record object into the form widget
- update the doctrine object with the posted value

And most of the times you should use `updateDefaultsFromObject` and `doUpdateObject` symmetrically.

To load back the saved values override [updateDefaultsFromObject](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/form/sfFormDoctrine.class.php#L257):

```
// maybe you have to declare it as public if the parent class requires that
protected function updateDefaultsFromObject()
{
  parent::updateDefaultsFromObject();

  if (isset($this['no_emisor'])
  {
    $this->setDefault('no_emisor', $this->getObject()->getSdrivingMaquinaEmisor()->getIdemisor());
  }
}

// and you can simplify this a little bit as well
protected function doUpdateObject($values)
{
  parent::doUpdateObject($values);

  if (isset($this['no_emisor']))
  {
    $this->getObject()->getSdrivingMaquinaEmisor()->setIdemisor($this->values['no_emisor']);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you take a look at my latest edit in the main post? I get lost about `doUpdateObject($values)` function and the code you leave me here in your answer

Comment: never mind I figure out and it's working, many thanks and let me said your suggestions help me a lot during this past days not only in this post, thanks